# mysql change column for filter

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

here is my query

```
    select op.*,o.customers_name from orders_payment op, ".TABLE_ORDERS. " o where op.orders_id=o.orders_id  AND 
o.customers_id='".$customers['customers_id']."' 
AND op.confirm_payment='1' 
AND (received_date BETWEEN '".$fromdate."' AND '".$todate."') order by pay_id desc
```

what I want to modify in this is 'payment_date'column filter. If this column is empty then replace it with 'payment_date' else remain same.
I tried a switch statement but didn't get any success.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `case`:

```
((received_date BETWEEN (case when '".$fromdate."' = '' then pament_date else '".$fromdate."' end) AND '".$todate."') or
 (payment_date BETWEEN (case when '".$fromdate."' = '' then pament_date else '".$fromdate."' end) AND '".$todate."')
)
```

Along the way, I would strongly advise you to use parameters ranging than munging the SQL string.  At the very least, you could then pass in `NULL` and use `coalesce()` rather than `case`.